# IIS6.0 Enable HttpCompression for specific extensions at site level

Tags: iis, compression, http-compression

I want to enable HttpCompression in IIS6.0 using adsutil.vbs. I understand that i can enable it for generic server level as well as for a specific website under IIS. (I used this http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/502ef631-3695-4616-b268-cbe7cf1351ce.mspx?mfr=true as a primary resource)..

However my question is different. I want to specify the extensions (asmx to be precize) to be compressed. That's perfectly doable at the webserver level but somehow I am not able to understand, how can i set it up ***at the site level*** . This is required because, in a deployment scneario, there could be multiple web apps hosted under same IIS and client is not interested in turning on compression on asmx other than my app.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While researching further, I came across [this resource](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpcompression%20this%20resource) which has explained about enabling the compression at site level.

In a nut shell here are the steps

1. Open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager:
2. In the Connections pane, go to the connection, site, application, or directory for which you want to enable compression.
3. In the Home pane, double-click Compression.
4. In the Compression pane, check the boxes to enable static or dynamic compression, or remove the check marks to disable static or dynamic compression.
5. Once you have completed the above steps, click Apply in the Actions pane.